# Explanation for the coefficients of L-function of an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I am reading about L-functions of Elliptic curves from Milne's notes. The definition of the L-function of an Elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb Q$ is $$L(E,s)=\prod_{p\text{ good}} (1-a_pp^{-s}+p^{1-2s})^{-1}\prod_{p\text{ bad}}(1-a_pp^{-s})^{-1}$$
where for good primes $p$, we have that $a_p=\begin{cases}\#\tilde{E}(\mathbb F_p)&\text{good reduction at }p\\0 &\text{ additive reduction at }p\\1& \text{multiplicative split reduction at } p\\-1&\text{multiplicative non-split reduction at }p\end{cases}$

> I am unable to understand the rationale behind the choice of the coefficients of the $p$-factors of the $L$-functions. The only possible explanation that I have found out till now is that the functional equation is satisfied because of the choice.

I would prefer a clearer and more natural explanation for the coefficients. Some historical background is also appreciated.

Comment: For good reduction, it should be $a_p=p+1-\#\tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

Answer (score 3):

This is the so-called *Hasse-Weil L-function* of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is defined as the product over its local $L$-series:
$$
L(E,s):=\prod_p L_p(E,s)^ {-1},
$$
related to the [Hasse-Weil Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%E2%80%93Weil_zeta_function), i.e., by
$$
Z_{E,\mathbb{Q}}(s)=\frac{\zeta(s)\zeta(s-1)}{L(E,s)}
$$
Regarding your question: there is really a lot of mathematics going on behind this definition. This has been explained on this site and at Mathoverflow already quite good. A starting point could be this question:

[$L$-functions of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664099/l-functions-of-elliptic-curves-over-mathbbq)

Comment: Let $E : y^2=x^3-ax-b$ and $R = \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-ax-b)$. Then $Z_{E(\mathbb{Q})}(s) = \zeta_R(s) = \prod_{\mathfrak{m}} \frac{1}{1-(N\mathfrak{m})^{-s}}$ where $N\mathfrak{m}=\#\ R/\mathfrak{m}$, $\mathfrak{m} = (p,f(x),g(x,y))$ where $P \in E(\mathbf{F}_p)$, $f \in \mathbf{F}_p[x]$ the minimal polynomial of $x_P$ and $g \in \mathbf{F}_p[x]/(f(x))[y]$ the minimal polynomial of $y_P$. If we have unique factorization of ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ with $R/\mathfrak{a}$ finite, then $\prod_{\mathfrak{m}} \frac{1}{1-(N\mathfrak{m})^{-s}} = \sum_\mathfrak{a} (N\mathfrak{a})^{-s}$

Comment: I didn't say wikipedia isn't correct, I'm just saying this is the clearly the motivation of Hasse-Weil zeta functions.

Comment: I see. So this is also not mentioned in the linked question, that's what you want to say. Yes, there are more motivations, indeed. I did not want to summarize it myself. The link is just a help to read further.

Comment: A step to obtain what I wrote is :
For a fixed $p$ let  $M_k = \# \{\mathfrak{m}, N\mathfrak{m} = p^k\}$ then $\log \prod_{\mathfrak{m}} \frac{1}{1-(N\mathfrak{m})^{-s }} = -\sum_{k=1}^\infty M_k \log(1-p^{-sk}) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{l=1}^\infty M_k\frac{p^{-slk}}{l}$ $ = \sum_{m=1}^\infty p^{-sm} \sum_{k | m}\frac{M_k}{m/k} =\sum_{m=1}^\infty p^{-sm} \frac{\# E(\mathbf{F}_{p^m})}{m}$ ie. $ \# E(\mathbf{F}_{p^m}) = \sum_{k | m} k M_k$ which is explained for example in Milne's book : points on $E(\mathbf{F}_{p^k})$ are  morphisms $\mathbb{Z}[E] \to \mathbf{F}_p[E] \to \mathbf{F}_{p^k}$.